# How to run shell script in another server in a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

No where online can i find a way to run a shell script on a remote server from another script. This is for automation, so the script on the host machine will automatically trigger another script on a different server. The server that my script will ssh to will either have a password prompt or have RSA key pair set up

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, using `expect package`.

> Disclaimer: This you can use for testing environments since it has an
>   open password. but depends on your usecase

If your server does not have `expect`, you may add the package then. run the command. You can also put this command inside an `.sh` script.

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@10.11.12.13 "/path/to/my.sh"; expect "assword:"; send "Y0urp@ssw0rd\r"; interact'
```

Answer (score 6):

Just pass the command as an argument to ssh.

```
ssh someserver /path/to/some/script.bsh
```

Comment: Im not trying to do this via command line but as a script, there will be no manual typing to trigger the script.

Comment: This does not require manual typing if the RSA key pair is set up in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to execute a script on node2 but you have your script on node1 file name of script is *sp* over location /home/user/sp. Simply

```
ssh node2 < /path-of-the-script-including-the-filename
```